Is there a connection between Bastion’s backstory involving his parents in X-Men '97 and the original animated series?
In the X-Men '97 episode "Tolerance Is Extinction - Part 1" (Season 1, Episode 8), we get a glimpse into Bastion's backstory when Jean Grey reads the psychic imprint of a drawing he made as a child. According to what Jean saw, Bastion's father, who worked as a school janitor, was somehow infected by something from the future—Sentinel technology, or Nimrod, to be precise.
Now, this version of Bastion's origins is quite different from his comic book counterpart, where he was born through mystical or magical means and had no biological parents. In the comics, his "mother," Rose, was more of a surrogate figure who adopted him later on.
I can't help but wonder if the X-Men '97 writers intentionally changed Bastion's backstory to tie it closer to the classic '90s X-Men: The Animated Series. Perhaps they were referencing events from that show where Bastion's father might have been exposed to futuristic Sentinel tech or Nimrod in some capacity.
Were Bastion's biological parents featured in X-Men: The Animated Series? If so, which episode(s) did they appear in, and portrayed the events leading to his father’s encounter with futuristic Sentinel tech / Nimrod?
